# Why isn't blog posts being imported via RSS on Facebook anymore?

Tags: facebook

I am trying to import a blog and well I cannot even find the option to import anymore. It is not even on the right side anymore. I ensured that there were no extensions applied, blocking it from appearing. Has Facebook removed this option, I had it saved in my bookmarks

> https://www.facebook.com/editnotes.php?import

I hope not, otherwise I would hope someone would explain to me the reasoning behind removing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, Facebook has [stopped Import notes feature](https://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=277347965620183#Why-can-I-no-longer-import-posts-from-my-website-to-my-Page%27s-notes?):

> We want you to connect with your fans in the most effective ways possible. That's why as of September 30th you'll no longer be able to automatically import posts from your website to your Page notes. The best way to get people to interact with your content is to give them insight into the links you share on your Wall by adding personal comments and responding to feedback from fans.
>
> We're focused on creating even better tools for Pages. Look for announcements soon.